# TypeScript mapped types debugging

Tags: typescript

I'd like to know how to debug mapped types in TypeScript.

For example:

```js
type Foo<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Array<any>? true:false; // here I want to know P value in each iteration
}
```

I found [unit tests](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/71c1da020f310ece5297e506233c839c8dd55cf5/tests/cases/conformance/types/mapped) for mapped types in TS repo, but still don't know how to debug them.

So, I'm looking for the place in code where I just can log `T[P]` or `P` variable in above iteration.