# How can I "debug" complex TypeScript types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

When creating complex types in TypeScript (e.g. recursive types, inferences, etc.) it's really hard to follow what TypeScript is doing inside it's Blackbox.

Too often I find myself having to do something like the following just to understand what happend:

[image: Code example]

I would like to be able to "debug" what TypeScript is doing and follow its logical path while it is evaluating my types, without substituting my code or commenting-out parts.
It's like setting a breakpoint, but not at runtime...

Is there any course of action, or any tool, I could adopt to facilitate the creation of my types?

Thanks in advance,
Shy Agam.

Comment: In order to do that, you need to use `typescript compiler api`. Also, please see my questions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926297/how-to-get-full-ast-representation-of-union-type-in-typescript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62196895/typescript-mapped-types-debugging). Apart from TS compiler API, because it is very complicated for me, I use error messages wrapped into template literal strings, like [here](https://catchts.com/email-validation)

Comment: You really opened up my mind there. Thanks. I read some of the docs and threads. Unfortunately, it seems like it would take a lot of learning just to start using the API, then a lot of trail and error to create something useful. I hope the TypeScript team will eventually develop an expression debugger.